# Is the 4th dimension an infinite set of 3rd dimensions?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, arrow-of-time

My understanding goes like this: an x-y plane (or flat 2-dimensional surface) is an infinite set of lines, each one dimensional. The x-y-z space (or 3d volume) is an infinite set of 2-dimensional planes. So the 4th dimension must be an infinite set of 3-dimensional volumes, right?

My question is, if we see the world like this then is time not an arrow but a collection of well-defined events that is predetermined?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the 4th dimension is just another (single) dimension!  So your question could be more like: "Is 4-dimensional space an infinite set of 3-dimensioal spaces".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can think of it this way.  You could also have started with 1 dimension and stated that it is an infinite set of points.  With regard to the flow of time, this is indeed one of the challenges of General Relativity (GR).  One of the interpretations within GR is that the flow of time is simply a collection of events which the human mind organizes/interprets as the flow of time.

Answer (score 2):

The picture of physical events which you are referring to here is called the "block universe". If basic physical patterns ("laws") are all deterministic then the block universe picture makes a lot of sense. If the basic physical patterns ("laws") are not entirely deterministic then the future is not entirely fixed by the past so the block universe picture becomes more questionable. In the latter case whenever some event is truly not determined by what led up to it (e.g. a random number generator with genuine randomness) then the future light cone of that event is not determined for any observer for whom the event is not in their past light cone.